# SSAS Vs Pentaho

Tags: ssas, pentaho

We are in a situation to decide one among MS SSAS and Pentaho. Is there any comparision list for both of them with pros and cons? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pentaho. I'm using MS Analysis, Integration and Reporting for two years. A lot of bugs, very weak error reporting, monsterous products. A lot of lags in design time. If you need more coplex answer ask your questions what side of thees products you interestd in.